# Add another key...value pair to objects

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects, key-value

I want to add more key... value pairs to each of the objects. Is it possible to do that?

Right now I have objects that look like:

```
{"year":2014,"num":115.5}
{"year":2016,"num":0.0}
{"year":2017,"num":8.28}
{"year":2018,"num":0.0}
```

I have an array of colors:

```
 let colors = ['#42d4f4','#e6194B','#3cb44b','#911eb4'];
```

I want to now add these colors to my objects.

I want to make it look like so:

```
{"year":2014,"num":115.5, "colors": '#42d4f4'}
{"year":2016,"num":0.0, "colors": '#e6194B'}
{"year":2017,"num":8.28, "colors": '#3cb44b'}
{"year":2018,"num":0.0, "colors": '#911eb4'}
```

Is there a way for me to do that without writing many many if's?

Comment: How exactly do you _"have"_ these objects? Are they in an array? What happens if there's more objects than `colors`?

Comment: How do you associate the colour with the object? A bunch of objects have no order.

Comment: `Is there a way for me to do that...?` It's generally good form to show what you've tried, there are at least several ways that come to mind: for/of loop, traditional for loop, or Array.prototype functions map() and reduce().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` to loop thru the array. Use spread syntax to shallow copy the object and add the `colors` property using the index.

```js
let arr = [{
  "year": 2014,
  "num": 115.5
}, {
  "year": 2016,
  "num": 0.0
}, {
  "year": 2017,
  "num": 8.28
}, {
  "year": 2018,
  "num": 0.0
}];

let colors = ['#42d4f4', '#e6194B', '#3cb44b', '#911eb4'];

let result = arr.map((o, i) => ({ ...o, colors: colors[i] || null }));

console.log(result);
```

---

If you want to update the existing variable, you can use `forEach`

```js
let arr = [{
  "year": 2014,
  "num": 115.5
}, {
  "year": 2016,
  "num": 0.0
}, {
  "year": 2017,
  "num": 8.28
}, {
  "year": 2018,
  "num": 0.0
}];

let colors = ['#42d4f4', '#e6194B', '#3cb44b', '#911eb4'];

arr.forEach((o, i) => o.colors = colors[i] || null);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: @RobG I'd always favour immutability over direct modification

Answer (score 1):

You can map over the array and return all of the objects with a new key `color`.

```js
let data =[
  {"year":2014,"num":115.5},
  {"year":2016,"num":0.0},
  {"year":2017,"num":8.28},
  {"year":2018,"num":0.0}
];
let colors = ['#42d4f4','#e6194B','#3cb44b','#911eb4'];
let newData = colors.map((color, index) => ({...data[index], color}));
console.log(newData);
```

If you're not familiar with ES6 syntax, this is the same as:

```js
let data =[
  {"year":2014,"num":115.5},
  {"year":2016,"num":0.0},
  {"year":2017,"num":8.28},
  {"year":2018,"num":0.0}
];
let colors = ['#42d4f4', '#e6194B', '#3cb44b', '#911eb4'];
let newData = colors.map(function(colorHex, index) {
  return {
    year: data[index].year,
    num: data[index].num,
    color: colorHex
  }
})
console.log(newData) // [{"year":2014,"num":115.5, "colors": '#42d4f4'}, ...]
```